# cant break out of Python While loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm quite new to Python so sorry in advance, I'm trying to break out of a While loop if a random number is not within a List of numbers.
Despite testing the output of the functions and confirming that an integer is in the List and it is in fact an integer and other methods return both True and False the While Statement ignores the value. See demo code.

```
import random,time
list=[i for i in range(10)]
print(list)

print(list[6]*10) # this returns an integer
if list[6]==12/2:
    print('this evaluates as a int')

this=99 # sentry to run the while loop   **** but cant index by

if 10/2 in list:
    print('this also evaluates as an integer')
print(type(list))
print(type(this))
while this not in list:
    this = random.randrange(9)
    print(this,this in list)
    time.sleep(.200)
    list[this] = '*'

>>>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
60
this evaluates as a int
this also evaluates as an integer
<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
6 True
3 True
4 True
```

5 True

```
5 False
```

Comment: You reassign `this` before you print it. So you see a different value than the one that was last evaluated in the while loop.

Comment: Futhermore with `list[this] = '*'` you set the element on position `this` to `*`. So the items will be replace with `*` and `this not in list` cannot be `True`.

Comment: You should better explain what you actually want to do to help you. The whole program doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I want the While loop to iterate through the loop whilst an integer 0 to 9 exists within the List, I use the '*' to remove that integer once it has been used. I want to break out of the loop when no integer remains in the List

Answer (score 1):

The while loop condition should evaluate to `False` when you want to break out of the loop. In your case, since you want to exit when `this is not in list`, then set your condition to `this in list`.

Here is your code with the fixed condition, keep in mind that since the list is directly modified from inside the loop, the loop will terminate after one iteration.

```py
import random, time
list=[i for i in range(10)]
print(list)

this = random.randrange(9)

while this in list:
    this = random.randrange(9)
    print(this, this in list)
    time.sleep(.200)
    list[this] = '*'
    print(list)
```

If you did not want the loop to terminate after one iteration, you may want to consider relocating the expression `list[this] = '*'`. (Though this solution may also end after one iteration based on probability)

```
import random, time
list=[i for i in range(10)]
print(list)

this = random.randrange(9)

while this in list:
    list[this] = '*' # moved here
    print(list)
    this = random.randrange(9)
    print(this, this in list)
    time.sleep(.200)
```

#### EDIT based on comment

Since the goal is to replace integers with *'s until no integers remain in the original list, here are some modifications.

The while loop exits when the number of elements replaced is equal to the number of items in the original array. The indices that have not been replaced yet are stored in the array called `available`.

```
import random, time
lst = [i for i in range(10)]
print(lst)

num_replaced = 0
# available = list.copy()
available = list(range(len(lst)))
while num_replaced < len(lst):
    this = random.choice(available)
    available.remove(this) # the index just chosen is no longer available
    lst[this] = '*'
    num_replaced += 1
```

Comment: I want the While loop to iterate through the loop whilst an integer 0 to 9 exists within the List, I use the '*' to remove that integer once it has been used. I want to break out of the loop when no integer remains in the List.

Comment: This won't work if there are duplicates in the list. Also not great practice to shadow built-ins (like `list`) even if that's what the original poster did. Better to call it something else, and explain why.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. It would probably be better to let `available` refer to the available indices, i.e. `available = list(range(len(lst)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious there's a flaw in the While function where it is unable see True or False correctly, thank you to those who proposed suggestions but i come up with my own.
I created a sentry boolean to pass the value to the While function

```
sentry=True
while sentry:
    this = random.randrange(9)
    print(this,this in list)
    if this not in list:
        sentry=False
    time.sleep(.200)
    list[this] = '*'
```